# Check if field contains any numbers?

Tags: forms, validation, vba, ms-access

Hi I'm trying to write some VBA so that it checks whether one of my text boxes contains a number. The text box is called: CustomerName. Here's the code I am currently using:

```
Function HasNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
    Dim iCnt As Integer

    For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
            HasNumber = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iCnt

End Function

Private Sub CustomerName_AfterUpdate()
If HasNumber(CustomerName) Then
    MsgBox "Only letters are allowed for this field."
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

For some reason when I enter numbers into this field and then click out of it (i.e. update it) it doesn't come up with a msgbox or anything. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using some custom code, I would use this validation rule on the `CustomerName` column of your table, or on the validation rule of your text box:

```
Not Like "*[0-9]*"
```

See here for a reference of [validation rules](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
If HasNumber(CustomerName.Text) Then
```