# Syntactic for Find Replace cells in a range that have a "space" to empty not right

Tags: excel, vba

I need to replace `all` cells in column B such that if the cell content has a space between two words e.g `abc cde` then replace the content with `" "` i.e make that cell empty.

I think I can do it with a `find/replace and wildcard` I am tring `What:="""*"" ""*"""`

the macro runs but nothing is replaced

Thank you

```
Sub Replace()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LR As Long

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)

    rng.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="""*"" ""*""", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   [A2].Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with **Regular Expressions**

Comment: The cells I keep all have `Numbers` in them and the cell I want to make Empty do not have `Numbers` in them, maybe if I search on partial for numbers?, I will try

Comment: @Tim, just change `What:="""*"" ""*"""` to `What:="* *"`

Answer (score 0):

I continued my search and fond something I could alter
[Check if field contains any numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471740/check-if-field-contains-any-numbers)

```
Sub CustomerName_AfterUpdate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim acell As Range
Dim LR As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXX")
 LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)

For Each acell In rng
If HasNumber(acell.Text) Then

Else
  acell.Value = " "
End If
Next acell

End Sub

Function HasNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
Dim iCnt As Integer

For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
        HasNumber = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next iCnt

End Function
```